# Time variable not being passed somewhere in these methods

Tags: ruby, variables, time, arguments

There aren't any error messages showing up once the code is run, I've resolved all of those before posting here.  This is just a simple greeting with a few methods, which takes the current time into account and asks for the user's name, but for some reason there's a hole where the time variable should be in the greeting.  This is my Ruby code here:

```
def determine_current_hour
   current_time = Time.new
   current_hour = current_time.hour
end

def greeting(name)
  current_hour = determine_current_hour
  if(current_hour > 3 && current_hour < 12)
     time = "morning"
  elsif(current_hour > 12 && current_hour < 18)
     time = "afternoon"
  elsif(current_hour > 18 || current_hour < 2)
     time = "evening"
  end
  puts "Good #{time}, #{name.capitalize}!"
end



puts "What is your name?"
name = gets

greeting(name)
```

And this is the resulting input and output:

```
What is your name?
Ruby
Good , Ruby
!
```

It seems airtight to me but I must be missing something.  Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: I got it finally, it just happened to be 18 when I wrote this out.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions do not account for the hour being 2, 3, 12 or 18 because they are all exclusive checks. In any of those hours you will see the output you describe.

Comment: Oh I see, so I'd have to tack on something like "elsif(current_hour == 2), time = "evening", elsif(current_hour == 3), time = "morning," etc. to fill in those 4 holes.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @Luke_the_Fonze You don't need to do that, you just need to use e.g. `>=` instead of `>` to include those values. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Greg Beech correctly points out, some hours are wrong because your conditions exclude them. For example, your first condition says `current_hour < 12` and your second condition says `current_hour > 12`, but if `current_hour` is *equal to* 12 it meets neither of those conditions. To fix it, either replace the comparison operator in the first condition with `<=` or in the second with `>=`:

```
def greeting(name)
  current_hour = determine_current_hour

  if current_hour >= 3 && current_hour < 12
    time = "morning"
  elsif current_hour >= 12 && current_hour < 18
    time = "afternoon"
  elsif current_hour >= 18 || current_hour < 3
    time = "evening"
  end

  puts "Good #{time}, #{name.capitalize}!"
end
```

This is pretty verbose, though. Might I suggest a more idiomatic approach using Ruby's versatile `case` construct?

```
def current_day_part
  case Time.new.hour
    when 3..11 then "morning"
    when 12..17 then "afternoon"
    else "evening"
  end
end

def greeting(name)
  puts "Good #{current_day_part}, #{name.capitalize}!"
end
```

Comment: That is too cool.  It just blows my mind how streamlined Ruby is